Resources for computing spectra of differential operators acting on functions with unbounded domains
What are some good textbooks or other resources that deal with finding/characterizing the spectra of differential operators acting on functions with unbounded domains? For an example of what I'm wanting help with, let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ (where $C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ denotes twice-continuosly differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$) and consider the operator
$$L:C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})\to C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$$
defined by
$$L[f]:=-\nabla^2f + S(r)f,$$
where $\nabla^2$ is defined by
$$\nabla^2f:=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_3^2}$$
(with $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ being the relevant coordinates for $\mathbb{R}^3$) and $S(r)\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ has spherical symmetry ($r:=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$). I'm looking for resources that will help me find $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$L[f]=\lambda f,$$
i.e. that will help me find (or at least characterize) $L$'s spectrum. I have been able to find many that deal with the case where $f$ has a bounded domain, but ones that consider the unbounded case seem to be more scarce. I appreciate any and all advice.

This looks almost exactly like the scattering problem for the Schrodinger equation. It isn't my area of expertise, but I suspect that mathematical treatments of quantum mechanics might have some useful material and references
